# Python - pandas / openpyxl: Tips on Automating Reports (Moving Away from VBA).

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas, reporting

I currently have macros set up to automate all my reports. However, some of my macros can take up to 5-10 minutes due to the size of my data.

I have been moving away from Excel/VBA to Python/pandas for data analysis and manipulation. I still use excel for data visualization (i.e., pivot tables).

I would like to know how other people use python to automate their reports? What do you guys do? Any tips on how I can start the process?

Majority of my macros do the following actions -

- Import text file(s)
- Paste the raw data into a table that's linked to pivot tables / charts.
- Refresh workbook
- Save as new

Comment: This question is quite broad for Stack Overflow, and may end up being closed for that reason. You might want to look into something like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). See how far you can get with it, and come back if you have specific issues with your code!

Answer (score 1):

I do data reporting often, and here are the tools that you can consider to help you out:

> 1. Python / pandas

It's great that you already are acquainted with pandas and Python. You can import text files which too large for Excel to read and manipulate them using something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/your/text.csv')
# carry out other data analysis like filtering, user-defined functions for special data manipulation etc.
```

You can also use numpy for data manipulation and functions.

> 2. Plotting of Charts

You can use matplotlib to plot charts:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = df.plot()
# manipulate charts by changing title, series, set intervals etc.
plt.show()
```

> 3. Exporting Files as New Excel Workbooks

And since you are using pandas, you can just use its `[to_excel()][1]` function to export your dataframes as new Excel Workbooks:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When using python to automate reports I fully converted the report from Excel to Pandas. I use pd.read_csv or pd.read_excel to read in the data, and export the fully formatted pivot tables into excel for viewing. doing the 'paste into a table and refresh' is not handled well by python in my experience, and will likely still need macros to handle properly ie, export a csv with the formatted data from python then run a short macro to copy and paste.

if you have any more specific questions please ask, i have done a decent bit of this

Comment: It should be pretty easy to automate your processes.  Use the suggestions described above.  Test whatever ideas you have and Google for solutions to things you don't understand.  I'm doing the same thing you are doing.  It just takes a little time to move from one environment to another, because they are totally different.  You are correct in your thinking that Python is infinitely faster than Excel.  Finally, check out the link below, to see how to auto-execute your Python processes.  https://shahronak47.wordpress.com/2016/11/30/scheduler-to-run-a-r-script-windows/